# SQLite Database Hangs Upon Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, sql-update

I've been grinding on a problem for a couple hours and would be grateful for any outside input. I am new to iOS, Objective-C and SQLite and trying to execute a SQLite Update statement. The issue is that the UI freezes and seems to hang up in a process within SQLite.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SQLite3Database.sqlite"];
SQLite3_instance *db = [SQLite3_instance databaseWithPath:path]; 
[db open];

NSString *execUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update ListItem set status=%i,message=\"%@\",GPSLong=%@, GPSLat=%@,lastUpdated=DateTime('now') where userID = %@",[Status_Picker selectedRowInComponent:0],messageTextField.text , longitude, latitude,loggedinUserID];
NSLog(@"execUpdate: %@", execUpdate);
if (![db executeUpdate:execUpdate])
    NSLog(@"Data insert failed %@", db.lastErrorMessage);
```

This code is executed in an IBAction after clicking a UIButton, but as previously mentioned, the UI is hung up in a process.  The output from the above code is the following:

****execUpdate: update ListItem set status=0,message="",GPSLong=44.48916, GPSLat=6.28739,lastUpdated=DateTime('now') where userID = 1****

Can anyone see how this code is hung up?

Looks like the issue was an Xcode memory leak.  After hours of pounding my head agains the wall, closing and starting it up again fixed the issue.

Comment: You should not string format the sql statement (injection etc...).  Use params.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424043/right-way-of-inserting-data-into-sqlite-db-iphone/10424264#10424264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure another process/thread didn't have a transaction open against the database? This would cause this behavior.

Comment: The issue turned up again and this was the issue. Good catch! Trying to get functionality working, I opened a new Sqlite database instance for each view controller (I know not good practice).  I've since changed this to pass the instantiated instance across viewcontrollers.